# Find the chromatic polynomial of a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring

[image: graph]

My answer: $p(g,k) = k(k-1)^4(k-2)(k-3) $

I'm new to this subject so was hoping if one of you could check my answer. Thanks.

Vertices:

[image]

Comment: Your answer says $p(g,3)=0$ so there are no ways to color it with $3$ colors? But I just did it: I colored the top vertex red, its two neighbors white, the the four bottom vertices alternately red and blue. So I think your answer must be wrong.

Comment: Do you know about Decomposition theorem in graph coloring?

Comment: @mathlover Nope. Does it have any relevance to finding the chromatic polynomial of a graph?

Comment: Yes..See any standard textbook of graph theory under section graph vertex coloring.

Comment: @bof So it would be chromatic polynomial = $k^3(k-1)^2(k-3)^2$? or do i plus them together not times?

Comment: The graph can be colored with $3$ colors but not with two. That tells me that $p(G,3)\gt0$ and $p(G,2)=0.$ That means that $k-2$ is a factor and $k-3$ is not. So your $k^3$(k-2)^2(k-3)^2$ can't be right. Somebody posted an answer, and I assume it's correct, though I didn't bother to check it.

Comment: @Trigamatuer you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Deletion.E2.80.93contraction this technique to solve this problem. 
As a base we know what is chromatic polynomial for a cycle. Then we observe that we need to somehow delete those two edges that are making it harder to calculate chromatic polynomial - just use deletion–contraction technique :)

Comment: @bof Whoops that $k-3$ is meant to be $k-2$, my bad.

Comment: I get $k(k-1)^2(k-2)^3+k(k-1)^2(k-2)^3+k(k-1)(k-2)^5$ which simplifies to $k(k-1)(k-2)^3(k^2-2k+2)$ which agrees with the answer posted by Zahra Taheri.

Comment: @bof i don't understand how you got that. Don't you just start at a vertex, name it k, then continue going through the vertices and whichever ones are touching another that has already been named you -1 to them?

Comment: Suppose the next vertex you want to color touches two vertices you've already colored, and you don't know if those two vertices have the same color or different colors. Say your graph is a $4$-cycle, vertices a, b, c, d and edges ab, bc, cd, da. You've got k ways to color a; then k-1 ways to color b, then k-1 ways to color c. Now what? Either k-1 or k-2 ways to color d, depending on whether a and c have the same color or different colors. So you have to consider cases. I could tell you how I worked it out for your graph, if you had labeled the vertices. Without labels it's too much trouble.

Comment: @bof I have uploaded an image with vertices, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: There is a *systematic* way of doing this; follow the link in Zahra Taheri's comment to his answer.

Comment: Using your labels, and starting from the top. **Case 1.** b,c have same color. k ways to color a; then k-1 ways to color b (different from a); then 1 way to color c (same as b); then k-1 colors for d (different from b); then k-2 colors for e (different from b and d). Now there are k-2 colors for f, different from c and e (we know c and e have different colors, because c has the same color as b which is different from e). Finally, k-2 colors for g. So the number of colorings in this case is $k(k-1)1(k-1)(k-2)(k-2)(k-2)=k(k-1)^2(k-1)^3.$

Comment: **Case 2.** b,c have different colors; c,e have same color. In this case I get $k(k-1)^2(k-2)^3$ colorings, same as before. **Case 3.** b,c have different colors; c,e have different colors. In this case I get $k(k-1)(k-2)^5$ colorings. Finally I add the results from the various cases to get the total number of colorings.

Comment: Note that assuming vertices $b$ and $c$ have different colors amounts to adding an edge $bc$ to the graph, while assuming they have the same color amounts to gluing those vertices together, making them into a single vertex.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

By Maple software, the chromatic polynomial of your graph, $G$, is $P(G,x)=x(x-1)(x^2-2x+2)(x-2)^3$. Its chromatic number is $3$ with vertex coloring $[[2, 5], [1, 3, 6], [4, 7]]$.

Comment: Any idea how to get this answer?

Comment: The following link may be helpful. https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/fouts.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi1wM7m_a7NAhUMBBoKHZUDBswQFggfMAU&sig2=JisDqOaLJMlt6KijZDsjBQ&usg=AFQjCNEsdnU_z8PuvXkQ7Qo5TcVeQZ2LzA